# Como puedo generar un id dinamico de 1 al 10 con js

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un problema al querer generar un id dinamico para mis input de un formulario...

```
    $(function() {
  $('#imagen1').change(function(x) {
      addImage(x); 
     });
     function addImage(x){
      var file = x.target.files[0],
      imageType = /image.*/;

      if (!file.type.match(imageType))
       return;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = fileOnload;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
     function fileOnload(x) {
      var result=x.target.result;
      $('#imagen1salida').attr("src",result);
     }
  });
```

lo que yo quiero hacer es que esta funcion de previzualizacion de imagenes se ejecute 10 veces pero con ids diferentes, por ejemplo $('#imagen2'), $('#imagen3'), $('#imagen4').
Basicamente lo que quiero es hacer un for que me genere esos numeros que van despues de la imagen, que seria algo asi $('#imagen'+variable+''); para no tener que copiar esa funcion 10 veces.

Probe de esta forma pero no me funciona:

```
 var numero = "";
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  numero += i;
  prueba = numero;
 $(function() {
  $('#imagen'+prueba+'').change(function(x) {
      addImage(x); 
     });
     function addImage(x){
      var file = x.target.files[0],
      imageType = /image.*/;

      if (!file.type.match(imageType))
       return;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = fileOnload;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
     function fileOnload(x) {
      var result=x.target.result;
      $('#imagen'+prueba+'salida').attr("src",result);
     }
  });
}
```

este es el formulario, estoy trabajando con Laravel por cierto.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="imagen1">Pregunta 1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion1}}">
                <input id="imagen1" type="file" name="imagen1" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen1)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: none;">
                <br>
                <label for="imagen1">
                    <img id="imagen1salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen1)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imagen2">Pregunta 2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion2}}">
                <input id="imagen2" type="file" name="imagen2" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen2)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: none;">
                <br>
                <label for="imagen2">
                    <img id="imagen2salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen2)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imagen3">Pregunta 3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion3}}">
                <input id="imagen3" type="file" name="imagen3" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen3)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: none;">
                <br>
                <label for="imagen3">
                    <img id="imagen3salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen3)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imagen4">Pregunta 4</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion4}}">
                <input id="imagen4" type="file" name="imagen4" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen4)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, Image/bmp" style="display: none;">
                <br>
                <label for="imagen4">
                    <img id="imagen4salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen4)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imagen5">Pregunta 5</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion5}}">
                <input id="imagen5" type="file" name="imagen5" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen5)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: none;">
                <br>
                <label for="imagen5">
                    <img id="imagen5salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen5)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imagen6">Pregunta 6</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion6}}">
                <input id="imagen6" type="file" name="imagen6" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen6)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: none;">
                <br>
                <label for="imagen6">
                    <img id="imagen6salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen6)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imagen7">Pregunta 7</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion7}}">
                <input id="imagen7" type="file" name="imagen7" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen7)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: none;">
                <br>
                <label for="imagen7">
                    <img id="imagen7salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen7)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imagen8">Pregunta 8</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion8}}">
                <input id="imagen8" type="file" name="imagen8" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen8)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: none;">
                <br>
                <label for="imagen8">
                    <img id="imagen8salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen8)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imagen9">Pregunta 9</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion9}}">
                <input id="imagen9" type="file" name="imagen9" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen9)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: none;">
                <br>
                <label for="imagen9">
                    <img id="imagen9salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen9)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imagen10">Pregunta 10</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion10}}">
                <input id="imagen10" type="file" name="imagen10" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen10)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: none;">
                <br>
                <label for="imagen10">
                    <img id="imagen10salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen10)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
            </div>
```

Espero y se entienda mi pregunta.. desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta esto: `$('#imagen' + i).change(function(x) {`

Comment: ya lo intente y no me funciono.. :/

Comment: Puedes subir tu HTML para poder ayudarte?

Comment: ya lo subi Hugo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cuestiones aquí, fijate el javascript los id que está generando:

```js
var numero = "";
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  numero += i;
  prueba = numero;
 $(function() {
  console.log("prueba:",prueba);
  $('#imagen'+prueba+'').change(function(x) {
      addImage(x); 
     });
     function addImage(x){
      var file = x.target.files[0],
      imageType = /image.*/;

      if (!file.type.match(imageType))
       return;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = fileOnload;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
     function fileOnload(x) {
      var result=x.target.result;
      $('#imagen'+prueba+'salida').attr("src",result);
     }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**1)**
`numero` es una cadena así que al agregarle `i` se va convirtiendo en `1`, `12` ... `123456789`, `12345678910`.

**2)**
Al poner `$(function() {` dentro de un `for` estás agregando eventos al `documentready` que se van a ejecutar todos juntos cuando cargue la página.

**3)**
Las variables en javascript son referencias a un objeto en memoria, así que al cambiar `numero` y asignarlo a `prueba` cuando realmente se ejecuten los `$('#imagen'+prueba+'').change(function(x) {` van a tener todos el mismo id: `#imagen12345678910`.

**4)** 
Algo parecido sucede al querer usar `prueba` para buscar la imagen correspondiente a cada input file, hay que capturar el id de cada input file y pasarselo a cada uno de los readers que se crean (asi cada reader sabe a que imagen cambiarle el src)

---

Un código adaptado a evitar estas cosas sería algo así:

```js
var i;
// sacamos las funciones hacia afuera del docready
function addImage(x) {
  var file = x.target.files[0],
    imageType = /image.*/;

  if (!file.type.match(imageType))
    return;

  var reader = new FileReader();
  // guardamos el ID del input[file] dentro de cada reader
  reader.elId = x.target.id;
  reader.onload = function(x) {
    var result = x.target.result;
    // recuperamos el ID y apuntamos a la img
    $('#' + x.target.elId + 'salida').attr("src", result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

// una sola funcion docready
$(function() {
  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    var selector = '#imagen' + i;
    console.log("selector:", selector);
    $(selector).change(function(x) {
      addImage(x);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Por otro lado y debido a que los ID en tu código siempre son de un `input` de tipo `file`, podés resumir un poco sin tener que generar las `ID`, algo así:

```js
var i;
// sacamos las funciones hacia afuera del docready
function addImage(x) {
  var file = x.target.files[0],
    imageType = /image.*/;

  if (!file.type.match(imageType))
    return;

  var reader = new FileReader();
  // guardamos el ID del input[file] dentro de cada reader
  reader.elId = x.target.id;
  reader.onload = function(x) {
    var result = x.target.result;
    // recuperamos el ID y apuntamos a la img
    $('#' + x.target.elId + 'salida').attr("src", result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}


// una sola funcion docready
$(function() {
  // un solo selector para todos
  $('input[type="file"]').change(function(x) {
    addImage(x);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="imagen7">Pregunta 7</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion7}}">
  <input id="imagen7" type="file" name="imagen7" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen7)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: block;">
  <br>
  <label for="imagen7">
                    <img id="imagen7salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen7)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="imagen8">Pregunta 8</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion8}}">
  <input id="imagen8" type="file" name="imagen8" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen8)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: block;">
  <br>
  <label for="imagen8">
                    <img id="imagen8salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen8)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="imagen9">Pregunta 9</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion9}}">
  <input id="imagen9" type="file" name="imagen9" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen9)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: block;">
  <br>
  <label for="imagen9">
                    <img id="imagen9salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen9)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="imagen10">Pregunta 10</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$encuesta->opcion10}}">
  <input id="imagen10" type="file" name="imagen10" value="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen10)}}" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp" style="display: none;">
  <br>
  <label for="imagen10">
                    <img id="imagen10salida" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$encuesta->imagen10)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width: 100px;"/>
                </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta.. me fue de gran ayuda.. Solucionado!

Answer (score 0):

Estás teniendo un par de problemas, el `$(function() { })` tiene que envolver todo el script, vos lo estás creando en cada ciclo `for`. Y cuando utilizás la variable `prueba` en `$('#imagen'+prueba+'')` estás teniendo un error ya que eso devuelve un `string` vacío, entonces no te agrega el método `change()`.

Deberías cambiar eso y ya quedaría utilizando `$('#imagen'+ i)`.

```
$(function() {
  function addImage(ev, i) {
    var file = ev.target.files[0],
    imageType = /image.*/;

    if (!file.type.match(imageType))
    return;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var result = e.target.result;
      $('#imagen'+i+'salida').attr("src",result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    $('#imagen'+ i).change(function(event) {
      addImage(event, i);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Entiendo. ya lo intente de esa manera, pero cuando lo hago asi solo me hace la previzualizacion de la primera imagen del formulario, pero cuando meto el $(function() { dentro del for no cambia ni una imagen

Comment: Te muestra algún error? Es probable que las funciones deban estar por fuera, ya que estás re declarando algo ya existente y genere un conflicto.

Comment: la consola esta limpia.. voy a seguir probando

Comment: @HernanChaparro Prueba con el siguiente cambio que he realizado.

Comment: no me funciono @keith, mismos sintomas, no cambia la imagen y la consola sigue limpia..

Comment: el `i` no llega al `reader` correspondiente, habría que propagarlo como un atributo extra de `reader`

Comment: Ya lo solucione.. gracias por los aportes